Sharing audio file with ShareLink sends the file but other apps (except VLC player) can't detect it right
Here's how I am using ShareLink:
struct ShareableAudioFile: Transferable {
   let audioUrl: URL
   
   @available(iOS 16.0, *)
   static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
       FileRepresentation(contentType: .mpeg4Audio) { audio in
           SentTransferredFile(audio.audioUrl)
       } importing: { received in
           let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
           let copy = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(received.file.lastPathComponent)
           try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: received.file, to: copy)
           return Self.init(audioUrl: copy)
       }
   }
}

And called like so:
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    ShareLink(
        "",
        item: ShareableAudioFile(audioUrl: url),
        preview: SharePreview("Audio")
    )
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}

url is the full path of the .m4a audio file stored in the documents directory and I can play it in my app using AVAudioPlayer.
When sharing with this method, other apps including voice memos can't play this file, and can't detect audio duration. However, if I share to my mac using airdrop (with the same ShareLink popup), VLC player is able to detect it and play correctly.
Since the file can be played by VLC, the permissions and content can't be a problem. Is there something wrong with the metadata here? I tried using .audio instead of .mpeg4Audio and still no luck. Also tried converting the content to Data and using DataRepresentation without success.
